# Download file with http header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest, pdf

I'm looking for dowloading PDF files with html links with HTTP authentication header.

It is not possible to fix them without javascript, so I tried this :

Html :

```
<a id="myLink" href="">fileName.pdf</a>
```

Javascript :

```
$("#myLink").on("click", function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", myUrl, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Token", authToken);
        xhr.send();
        return false;
});
```

File is downloaded (regards to network analysis) but I don't know how to open it in a new browser tab. I know we don't save files from javascript but I just want to display it. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't do that with javascript

Comment: I can't believe there's no solutions for displaying links to protected resources with html / javascript ?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is a specific use case. your `X-Token` sounds very proprietary. a cookie might be better.

Comment: X-Token is no proprietary (?) It's just an http header fixed to all ajax http request of my webapp.
The value is an auth key, retrieved from login request and stored in a cookie. Thks for your reply, I'm looking for sending cookie value automatically and I hope this will work.

Comment: browsers will send the cookie for the same path and domain.

Comment: any thing with the `X-` prefix is proprietary.

Comment: To my mind this is just conventional for specifying custom http header params, like "data-" for html attributes, am I wrong ?

Comment: Ok, now my cookie is given to request but resteasy seems not to considerer it as a header param :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to store header value inside a cookie.

When using RestEasy, cookie can be read inside an http filter (preProcess function for RestEasy 2.3.7.Final) with :

```
request.getHttpHeaders().getCookies()
```

request is an HttpRequest object.

There's still one "problem", files are never opened inside browser. I don't know how to fix this yet.